# How to open a specific file without user selection?

Tags: vb.net, file, file-upload

I currently have the following code which allows a user to select a file:

```
  Private Sub FileToolStripMenuItem1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles FileToolStripMenuItem1.Click
    Dim result As DialogResult
    Using filechooser As New OpenFileDialog()
        result = filechooser.ShowDialog()
        playFile = filechooser.FileName
    End Using
End Sub
```

What I am trying to do is have the program open a file on its own without user selection. Basically, i have a generic file that needs to be used for the application regardless of who is using it, and I want it to be uploaded automatically upon the application being started.

Comment: Start from here [Common I/O Tasks](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms404278(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 2):

You could just simply point your PlayFile directly by specifying the file

```
playFile = "C:\yourfile.txt" 'point to your file here
```